# using parse.com for android - query on array

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I hope it is ok to ask it here. I don't succeed to get the data from a query I made.

(I edit my code to use JSONArray)

This is my code:

```
    int myNumber = 42;
    String myString = "hellol";


    JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
    myArray.put(myString);
    myArray.put(myNumber);

    ParseObject bigObject = new ParseObject("BigObject");
    bigObject.put("myNumber", myNumber);
    bigObject.put("myString", myString);
    bigObject.put("myArray", myArray);
    bigObject.put("myNull", JSONObject.NULL);
    bigObject.saveInBackground();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BigObject");
    query.whereEqualTo("myNumber", myNumber);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (object == null) {
             Log.d("score", " not Retrieved the object.");
             toast("null");
        } else {
          Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
          try {
            toast(""+(object.getJSONArray("myArray").get(0)));
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
      }
    });
```

It is show me "null" in toast ..

And I have ont more questions:

What about 2 dimentional array - how can I add int[][] to database?

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-saving

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query.whereEqualTo("myString","hellol");
```

Comment: I don't know if it will help or not , but I need my query - check if the name is what I'm locking for and then use the array I will get

Answer (score 0):

Get your ObjectId like this:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("BigObject");

 query.getInBackground(bigObject.getObjectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
 public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
     if (e == null) {
         objectWasRetrievedSuccessfully(object);
     } else {
         objectRetrievalFailed();
     }
 }
}
```

Make it as array in the case of two dimentional..